# Intel C++ Compiler Issue with Uniform Initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, uniform-initialization

I have the following code that attempts to use uniform initialization of a std::array in the constructor:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

struct test_type_t {

   test_type_t(const std::array<double, 2> & arr) : arr_{arr} {}

   void print() {
      std::cout << "size: " << arr_.size() << std::endl;
   } // print

   std::array<double, 2> arr_;

};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {

   std::array<double, 2> array{ 1.0, 2.0 };
   test_type_t test{array};

   test.print();

   return 0;
} // main
```

This code compiles with g++ and clang++. However, Intel icpc (17.0.0 20160721) fails with:

```
icpc -g -O2 -std=c++14 -I. -c main.cc -o main.o
main.cc(9): error: no suitable conversion function from "const               
std::array<double, 2UL>" to "double" exists
    test_type_t(const std::array<double, 2> & arr) : arr_{arr} {}
                                                          ^
```

My question is, "Is this a bug in Intel icpc, or are g++ and clang++ being too permissive?"

Intel icpc compiles the code if I change 'arr_{arr}' to 'arr_(arr)' in the constructor.

Comment: [CWG issue 1467](https://wg21.link/CWG1467).